# Туннель IPSec работает, но почему я не могу пинговать IP-адреса назначения?

Tags: debian, ipsec

Оба сервера Debian, они же шлюзы

**Настройки 1 сервера:**

- ifconfig

> ```
> eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         ether 04:42:1a:08:7c:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
>         inet6 fe80::e21a:eaff:fe76:96f4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether e0:1a:ea:76:96:f4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 399930669  bytes 150437986833 (140.1 GiB)
>         RX errors 3  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 3
>         TX packets 507386332  bytes 412721154240 (384.3 GiB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>         device interrupt 16
>
> eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 1.1.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 1.1.1.255
>         inet6 fe80::6a05:caff:fef3:ba78  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether 68:05:ca:f3:ba:78  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 523293735  bytes 416686613426 (388.0 GiB)
>         RX errors 4  dropped 1264  overruns 0  frame 2
>         TX packets 387723159  bytes 149380371502 (139.1 GiB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>         device interrupt 16  memory 0xa0ac0000-a0ae0000
>
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
>         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
>         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>         RX packets 1362162  bytes 67625872 (64.4 MiB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 1362162  bytes 67625872 (64.4 MiB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```

- ipsec.conf

> ```
> config setup
>   charondebug="all"
>   uniqueids=yes
>
> conn ptgateway-to-bmgateway
>   type=tunnel
>   auto=start
>   keyexchange=ikev2
>   authby=secret
>   left=1.1.1.1
>   leftsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
>   right=2.2.2.2
>   rightsubnet=20.0.0.0/24
>   ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
>   esp=aes256-sha1!
>   aggressive=no
>   keyingtries=%forever
>   ikelifetime=28800s
>   lifetime=3600s
>   dpddelay=30s
>   dpdtimeout=120s
>   dpdaction=restart
> ```

- ipsec.secrets

> ```
> 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 : PSK "sdfsdfgvtgdtgdac032zVFKkrXdfddfv/ya04WzPA="
> ```

- route -n

> ```
> Kernel IP routing table
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> 0.0.0.0         1.1.1.241     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
> 10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
> 1.1.1.240     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth2
> ```

- ipsec status

> Security Associations (1 up, 1 connecting): ptgateway-to-bmgateway[3]:
> CONNECTING, 1.1.1.1[%any]...2.2.2.2[%any] ptgateway-to-bmgateway[1]:
> ESTABLISHED 11 minutes ago, 1.1.1.1[1.1.1.1]...2.2.2.2[2.2.2.2]
> ptgateway-to-bmgateway{4}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs:
> c6b23b59_i cef0242a_o ptgateway-to-bmgateway{4}:   10.0.0.0/24 ===
> 20.0.0.0/24

**Настройки 2 сервера:**

- ifconfig

> ```
> eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 2.2.2.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 2.2.2.255
>         inet6 fe80::642:1aff:fe08:7c7f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether 04:42:1a:08:7c:7f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 1322  bytes 124291 (121.3 KiB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 1017  bytes 208160 (203.2 KiB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 20.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 20.0.0.255
>         inet6 fe80::6a05:caff:fef3:bdb9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether 68:05:ca:f3:bd:b9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 421  bytes 38387 (37.4 KiB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 291  bytes 26543 (25.9 KiB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>         device interrupt 16  memory 0xa13c0000-a13e0000
>
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
>         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
>         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>         RX packets 4  bytes 156 (156.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 4  bytes 156 (156.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```

- ipsec.conf

> ```
> config setup
>   charondebug="all"
>   uniqueids=yes
>
> conn bmgateway-to-ptgateway
>   type=tunnel
>   auto=start
>   keyexchange=ikev2
>   authby=secret
>   left=2.2.2.2
>   leftsubnet=20.0.0.0/24
>   right=1.1.1.1
>   rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
>   ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
>   esp=aes256-sha1!
>   aggressive=no
>   keyingtries=%forever
>   ikelifetime=28800s
>   lifetime=3600s
>   dpddelay=30s
>   dpdtimeout=120s
>   dpdaction=restart
> ```

- ipsec.secrets

> ```
> 2.2.2.2 1.1.1.1 : PSK "sdfsdfgvtgdtgdac032zVFKkrXdfddfv/ya04WzPA="
> ```

- route -n

> ```
> Kernel IP routing table
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> 0.0.0.0         2.2.2.254     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
> 20.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
> 2.2.2.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
> ```

- ipsec status

> Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting): bmgateway-to-ptgateway[2]:
> ESTABLISHED 11 minutes ago, 2.2.2.2[2.2.2.2]...1.1.1.1[1.1.1.1]
> bmgateway-to-ptgateway{2}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs:
> cef0242a_i c6b23b59_o bmgateway-to-ptgateway{2}:   20.0.0.0/24 ===
> 10.0.0.0/24

Не пингуются ПК в обоих сетях.....

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо [Valentin Barbolin](https://qna.habr.com/user/dronmaxman) за неоценимую помощь!!!

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 ! -d 20.0.0.0/24 -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 20.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 20.0.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

и аналогично для второго сервера

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 20.0.0.0/24 ! -d 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -s 20.0.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 20.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```